# Declaring a variable inside if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why is the following not valid JavaScript?

```
if (var foo = (true || false)) {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: Log `true` to the console.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect this output? How do you believe this code should be executed? Why do you think that a variable *assignment* would return a boolean value?

Comment: `(true||false)` evaluates to true. The assignment of `foo` evaluates to true. The `if` checks the conditional which is the result of the assignment, whcih is `true`. The body of the if "should" then run. Clearly it is not valid JS, but my question is why?

Comment: an assignment would return the value of the variable it was assigned to. `if (foo = true)` would return true. it is just that the `var` keyword can not be used in a comparison. it's a statement, not a function.

Comment: That's a lexer's concern, var declaration has nothing to do in a condition statement

Comment: `(var foo = (true||false))` is an expression and not a statement, is it not?

Comment: it is an expression with a statement in it which isn't allowed there. `var foo` is a variable declaration which isn't allowed by the lexer, as @aduch already mentioned. Just like `if (;)` isn't valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5

then here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11

And conclude that the syntax isn't valid because of:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2

in relation (or rather lack thereof) to the above.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable in JavaScript the assignment will return the value of the new variable, so you can do something like this:

```
if (foo = (true||false)) console.log('Hello!');

> Hello!
```

Now if you call `foo` it will have a value of `true`:

```
console.log(foo);

> true
```

You **cannot** use the `var` private word, because `if` is a statement, not a function. If you want to be sure about the scope of your variable, then you have to declare it first:

```
var foo;
if (foo = (true||false)) console.log('Hello!');

> Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var foo = true || false;  
 if (foo) {
     console.log(foo);
  }
```

Place the declaration first and then check for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var foo;//declare the variable first
if (foo = (true || false)) { //then assign the value for foo
    console.log(foo);
}
```

---

You cannot create variable declaration inside if statement.